# Is there a shorter term for "divided by" in American English?

Tags: american-english, mathematics

Given the following expression:

> 5 (+-×÷%) 4

You would say "5 plus 4," "5 minus 4," "5 times 4," "5 divided by 4," and "5 mod(ulo) 4" respectively.

As far as I know, "divided by" does not have any shorthand form in the same way the above examples do.

Comment: "5 by 4" actually indicates multiplication in common usage (or, more properly, the dimensions of the sides of an object or matrix). The percentage sign is commonly used as the modulo operator in computer languages. By the same token, though, division is expressed by a virgule (/) rather than a division sign (÷) in those same languages.

Comment: @Jasper I included it because I'm into computer programming and it fit along with my examples. "5 mod 4" is how one would say it informally, but the correct phrasing is "5 modulo 4."

Comment: Isn't "by" also usually used to read a differential-- "dy/dx" > "dy by dx" doesn't strictly mean "dy over/divided by dx".

Comment: The way you phrase your question is [fallacious](http://philosophy.lander.edu/logic/complex.html). Might want to edit it. Also, the way it's phrased it identifies itself as too broad or vague, according to the FAQ. I'm just saying ...

Comment: In your example phrases, *plus*, *minus*, *times* and *modulo* are **not** verbs.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR You are correct. Feel free to edit as you see fit, because I am not entirely sure what they would be in this context.

Comment: @Corey: Nobody can tell you *why* there isn't a short term; a question that would fit EL&U would be: "is there a short term for division?"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Perhaps alternatives suffice to the extent that no great pressure exists to shorten "divided by"?

"5 over 4"?

"five fourths"?

Comment: "5 over 4" has a very different meaning in mathematics.

Comment: No, it doesn't -- it merely describes the statement as if it were written in fractional notation rather than as if it were written using the division sign (÷).

Comment: I almost always use "over." I also use "in(to)" sometimes, but that usually takes people a minute to figure out. Everyone I've worked homework problems with understands "over," though.

Comment: @jae: It most certainly does not.  Unfortunately the state of understanding of mathematics is so poor, that people think division, fractions, ratio, odds are all different things.  They are not.

Comment: @jae: I’ve only ever heard “over” used to mean “divided by”.  What is the other usage you’re familiar with for it?  I could imagine it also getting used for the “choose”/“combinations” notation for [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), but I don’t think I’ve ever actually heard that.

Comment: *wipes egg off face*  I *knew* not being a native speaker would show!  Dammit.  In German, it's "a über b", which would translate to "a over b", but... yes, I screwed up.  Well, nobody's perfect, not even I.

Comment: don't worry jae, I had the same connotation in mind. native germans speaker as well.

Comment: @jae, *strains to avoid traces of sarcasm* :)

Comment: I also expected "over" to mean binomial coefficients, since in Dutch (my native tongue), 'over' is exactly the word used for those cases. @PLL: how are _they_ called in English?

Comment: @Martijn: the pronunciation I’m familiar with is "*a* choose *b*".  I’m sure there are other options, though!

Comment: @kitukwfyer, *into* is the other way around, though: *five over four* is *four into five*.

Comment: @TRiG when I say "into" I'm thinking like "5 into fourths" or "5 turned into 4 pieces," not "5 goes into 4." As I said, it tends to catch people up. :)

Answer (score 3):

What about "per"? While not usually used in the same context as plus, minus, etc., it does mean "divided by".

Comment: As in 5 per 4 as an example for 5/4? That doesn't sound right, and most native english speakers wouldn't understand you.

Comment: It works for rates (which also involve division).  Five miles in four hours is the same as five-fourths of a mile per hour (1.25 MPH).  In that case, 1.25 miles per hour sounds much better than 1.25 miles over one hour (or 1.25 miles divided by one hour) even though they are both technically correct.

Comment: @advs89 But that's reserved pretty exclusively for dimensional analysis, and not actual division. You never simplify a "per" expression; you just cancel things which appear in both numerator and denominator. You wouldn't say "the ship was moving at 32 miles divided by hours" because that's not really accurate. In other words, you'll divide a *number* of miles by a *number* of hours, but you aren't actually dividing the *units* themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Invert the question/problem

4 into 5 goes 1.2 was the way I was brought up...

Comment: This is why division tables are sometimes colloquially called "gazindas". "4 gazinda 12 three times, 4 gazinda 16 four times, ..."

Answer (score 1):

I would use "5 by 4" in a generic setting like @Jasper mentioned. @Stan's point is valid, however in a matrix setting we're usually specific, like "A five by four matrix".
From what I've seen/heard/experienced, "5 times 4" is the colloquial norm for multiplication and "5 by 4" is the colloquial norm for division.

Comment: I don't think I'd interpret "by" as division unless there was a form of "divide" earlier in the sentence. *The result of dividing 5 by 4 is...*

Comment: The problem with *by* is that it's also used for material dimensions *sans* units. It would depend on the context, of course, but it could cause unnecessary confusion. In a purely mathematical discussion, there would likely be no problem, but when discussing applied mathematics in engineering or design, it's hard to tell where the pure numbers end and the materials begin.

Comment: Unfortunately “by” is very ambiguous — I’ve heard it used by some people to mean multiplication, by others to mean division.

Comment: This is a varieties-of-English thing. In India, "five by four" means "five divided by four", except in dimensions like "a nine-by-four room".

Comment: This implies multiplication not division.

Comment: I agree with @ShreevatsaR - I guess I was referring to an Indianized usage of the term